# Database.Query does not return fields with null value

Tags: soql, query, list, database, null

Hi i'm executing this query using

```
Database.Query(query)
```

Where query is

```
SELECT field1__c, field2__c, field3__c FROM Object1__c
```

On the current record, field3__c is NULL but when i query on the record instead of getting

```
"field1__c = value1", "field2__c = value2", "field3__c = null"
```

I get

```
"field1__c = value1", "field2__c = value2"
```

Just like the field has been deleted/not returned, which is a problem for our purpose.

The question is:

How can i get the null values returned as NULL or BLANK and not just "not returned"?

Comment: what is your purpose with that - there is actually no problem either in apex or in UI javascript?

Comment: that class is returning values to a flow which uses that field. If the field was returned as null or blank there are no issues, but if the field is not returned the flow will raise error cause "unable to access to the field"

Answer (score 4):

If you are checking in the debug logs, then that is how it will be displayed. It behaves the same for the normal `SOQL` query as well as for the dynamic `SOQL` i.e. with `Database.Query`

So, if you perform a SOQL on `Object1__c` with `field3__c` as `null`, then the debug will always show you

```
USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|Object1__c:{Id=0010o00002GxDELAA3, field1__c=CD355119-A, field2__c=1231313}
```

irrespective of whether you used normal `SOQL` or `Database.Query`. If you want to add a null check for `field3__c`, then you can do

```
List<Object1__c> objList = Database.Query('SELECT field1__c, field2__c, field3__c FROM Object1__c');
for(Object1__c obj : objList){
    //check for null for field3__c
    if(obj.field3__c != null){
    }
}
```

If you are passing this `field3__c` which to a flow i.e. a formula field, then you should have an additional check for related lookup field i.e. if your formula field's formula is `Account.AccountNumber` then have a check for `AccountId != NULL && field3__c != NULL` in flow. If you try to directly access `field3__c` or check for `NULL`, it will give you error. So always have an additional check for its lookup field as first check and then check for its related field.

Comment: I'm doing this but field3__c is a Formula Field so it's unwritable.
I need this field to be blank as needed but i need my query to return it as empty string or null.
I really cant realize why it's just not returned, how this logic of "not returning" could help any user?

Comment: @gmemo `I'm doing this but field3__c is a Formula Field so it's unwritable` What's that got to do with anything? The suggestion is to use it to check (if-statement), not write to. `I need this field to be blank as needed but i need my query to return it as empty string or null.` It is returning as blank/null. Do a System.debug() on the field itself and it will spit out its value of blank/null.

Comment: if i do a debug on field3 it corretly display as null. but if i pass the record to another method that access to that field from the record it says "unable to access to the field"
If i change the value of field3 to "test" or anything else different from null, it works.

Comment: If you are passing this `field3__c` which is a formula field to a flow, then have an additional check for related lookup field i.e. if your formula field is `Account.AccountNumber` then have a check for `AccountId != NULL && field3__c != NULL` in flow. If you directly try to access `field3__c` or check for `NULL`, it will give you error. So always have an additional check for its lookup field as first check and then check for its related field.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's late for my answer, but I was able to resolve this by initializing those fields manually after the SOQL call... just like this

```
LiveChatTranscript lct = [SELECT Id, ContactId, AccountId, Name FROM LiveChatTranscript WHERE Id =: lctId];
//Initialize ContactId and AccountId in case the SOQL query did not return the field because they are set to null
lct.ContactId = lct.ContactId;
lct.AccountId = lct.AccountId;
Flow.Interview flow = new Flow.Interview.Case_Create_CSAT_Survey(new map<String, Object> {'ChatTranscript' => lct});     
flow.start();
```

In my case, I was using those field in a flow and this flow is also called from process builder where we sent the LiveChatTranscript record so the field is there.
In the apex, it's being called in a future method so had to retrieve it manually, therefore just initializing the fields with themself worked.